# API/OS support for "9-bit" serial communication

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

Does java's [`javax.comm`](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/reference/api/index.html) library support "9-bit" serial communication? (use of parity bit or "address bit" as an out-of-band signaling mechanism for framing information)

Does the win32 communications API support it?

I'm guessing the answer is no on both counts, but figured someone has more experience with this than me.

Answer (score 1):

The win32 comm API does not support this as far as I can tell.

However, you can simulate it using the various parity modes.

Setting `MARKPARITY` will set the 9th bit to `1`

Setting `SPACEPARITY` will set the 9th bit to `0`

I can't say about the java version of the library, but I'm sure it supports setting parity modes so you can do the above and get your 9th bit.

Comment: That's for sending -- what about receiving?

Comment: (and i'd have to do it on a per byte basis... ugh... looks like it would be easier just to use base64 encoding to leave room for out of band information.)

Comment: yeah, it isn't pretty if you have to change it for every byte.  It should work for sending and receiving though

Answer (score 0):

Yout should follow this [Seeking FOSS serial port component which can handle 9 data bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9188015/463115).
Your main problem will be to handle 9-bit at all, as when the windows api can't handle it, how should java solve this?

Bt there exists professional cards/driver to solve this (see the link)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment on **karoberts** answer, but I lack reputation. So I have to "answer".

**karoberts** proposes a good way if *we need a software solution to our problem* (JCS citation, almost, isn't it? ))

But there may arouse a situation I faced today with Python (2.7) trying to do exactly the same thing: my PC refused to accept PARITY_MARK and PARITY_SPACE as options to configure my /dev/ttyS5. So I searched in Stack Overflow what can be done - and encountered this topic...

And I've found an answer in that (closed) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188015/seeking-foss-serial-port-component-which-can-handle-9-data-bits), **jeb** tells us in the next answer. **Tincho** points to an [article](http://electronicdesign.com/embedded/use-pcs-uart-9-bit-protocols) where it's proposed to set EVEN or ODD parity with each byte according to 2 factors: whether this is an address byte and what is the parity sum of it's bits.
I checked the solution and it works perfectly.